# ¿Por qué no puedo escribir en un Chat?

Tags: soporte, chat

Al responder una pregunta, un usuario ha creado un chat para poder continuar la discusión en él.

Cuando entro e intento escribir, ***no veo el modo, ni el lugar donde poder escribir.***

> Mi navegador:
>
> - Firefox Quantum 57.0.3 (64-bit)
> - He probado también con Microsoft Edge y me ocurre igual

**¿Puede ser algún problema de la herramienta?**

- [Link de la discusión](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71123/discussion-on-answer-by-alejandro-teixeira-munoz-como-continuar-setinterval-desp)
- Captura de la pantalla tal y como la veo.

[image: Pantalla de la sala de chat]

**PROBLEMA 2 - La página da error al hacer login Oauth con Facebook**

> Después de comprobar que el problema es que no estoy logeado, y que **al ser daltónico no veo los colores de la franja inferior**, veo que al intentar hacer login con Facebook, no parece permitirse.

[image: Captura pantalla error login con facebook]

Comment: El mensaje abajo dice que no estás logado.

Comment: Ole.... Soy daltónico y no veo nada del texto de abajo... Interesante punto a tener encuenta para la gente que tiene problemas de visión como yo :)

Comment: Tras loguearte has podido?

Comment: Nop, acabo de añadir el pantallazo. Parece que el oAuth no está bien confgurado, no?

Comment: Intenta borrar las cookies de tu navegador, puede que algo se haya atorado por ahí. Luego, vuelve a intentar.

Comment: Tras borrar las cookies del navegador (ojo, una nueva pestaña de incógnito no funcionaba). sí que ha funcionado.